# TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to create a webcam in Tkinter, but the `TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist` keep showing up, and I had no idea how to solve it after many attempts.

```
win = Tk()
win.geometry('700x350')

label = Label(win)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def show_frames():
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(cap1.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    
    label.after(20, show_frames)
    
show_frames()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is most probably that there are more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: Are you certain that _this_ code gives _this_ error? It seems unlikely.